# Is there any ways to create a Carousel in Watson Assistant

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have a project which needs to show a Carousel. **I tried many ways but no other things work for me. Tried many Javascript and HTML Carousel but none of them works in Watson.**  It has been for several days. It is really mandatory anyone who knows anyways please help me.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create carousels and other rich UI elements with [Botonic](https://botonic.io) (a React Framework for building conversational apps) and integrate it with Watson using the official [@botonic/plugin-watson](https://github.com/hubtype/botonic/tree/master/packages/botonic-plugin-watson)

Answer (score 0):

For one of our projects we also needed a picture carousel, which currently Watson Assistant via the rich formats does not support (i.e. multiple images within an array). We therefore created our own json rich response output that then triggered a carousel output within the Watson Web chat "client". You can extend the default Watson Web chat, to handle your own responses. See custom content for the Watson Web Chat (https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=api-render ) & custom response types. The original developer notes for the Watson Web Chat did have a carousel example, but don't see that there anymore.